# XIV pages in page counts?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

Is it possible to make biblatex output page counts for both the regular pages and the roman-numbered pages, for example:

> Cook, Theodore Andrea. The Curves of Life : Being an Account of Spiral Formations and Their Application to Growth in Nature, to Science and to Art; with Special Reference to the Manuscripts of Leonardo da Vinci. — London : Constable and Company, 1914. — xxx + 479 p.

Here there are "30 pages + 478 pages" in total. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried entering "xxx + 479" in the pagetotal field?  It is a literal field.

Comment: yes, but then it does not add the "p." at the end.

Comment: For literal page range references which are not auto-detected as such (usually only numbers are), you can manually add what you need with the macros like "\pno" from section 3.6.8 of the biblatex manual. See especially section 3.11.3 for examples like this.

Comment: Wow! Does this work in the actual bib file where I list the references? I'll try it out! Can you post your comment up as an answer - so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @PLK: Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually my comment above is incorrect as it only applies to citations, not the bibliography itself. However, you can tailor the allowed list of things that `\mkpagetotal` thinks are "numerals" and so in your example, all you should need to do is add this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareNumChars*{+}
```

This adds "+" to the "numeral" category and so `\mkpagetotal` will see "xxx + 179" as a numeral and append the right "p" or "pp" automatically for you.