# biblatex puts comma after bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

This is driving me crazy, biblatex decided for some reason to put a comma after one of my entries, in my bibliography.

My entry is:

```
  @mvbook{Kepler,
  author={Kepler, Johannes},
  editor={Frisch, Ch.},
  title={Joannis Kepleri astronomi opera omnia edidit Ch. Frisch},
  volume={I},
  address={Frankofurti a. M. et Erlangae},
  publisher={Heyder \& Zimmer},
  pages={XIV + XV--XVI + 1--672},
  date={1858},
  language={latin}
}
```

but here is how it looks (note the comma after 1858):

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) reproducing the problem mentioned.

Comment: What bibliography style are you using, and if you cite this item in a document by itself, can you reproduce the problem? If not, it's something to do with your actual document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the standard styles shipped with biblatex, the entry type `@mvbook` (multi-volume book) does not support the `pages` field. Use the `pagetotal` field instead and optionally tailor the `\mkpagetotal` list of "numerals" as shown in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16904/xiv-pages-in-page-counts/17083#17083) answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareNumChars*{+-}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Kepler,
  author={Kepler, Johannes},
  editor={Frisch, Ch.},
  title={Joannis Kepleri astronomi opera omnia edidit Ch. Frisch},
  volume={I},
  address={Frankofurti a. M. et Erlangae},
  publisher={Heyder \& Zimmer},
  pagetotal={XIV + XV--XVI + 1--672},
  date={1858},
  language={latin}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a wizard.