# Biblatex no printing "p." when page number ends in some letters

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Using `biblatex.sty 2013/01/10 v2.5` and `biber version: 1.5`, given

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{pages.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the .bib file

```
@Article{A,
  author =       {Some author},
  title =        {Some title},
  journal =      {Some journal},
  year =         2013,
  pages =        {1A}
}
```

the page number is generated as '1A' instead of 'p. 1A'.

Note 1: The same happens if I replace the 'A' in '1A' by some letter not belonging to Roman numerals, i.e. I, V, X, L, C, D or M.

Note 2: The same happens if I replace the `biber` backend by the `bibtex` one.

Note 3: If I remove `biblatex` and I use `bibtex` instead, I got the right result.

Comment: See also [XIV pages in page counts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16904/35864)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` uses the command `\mkpageprefix` to print the page numbers. Internal this command checks whether the input is a number or not. This is done by `\ifnumeral`:

In the documentation you can find the following explanation:

> ```
> \ifnumeral{⟨string⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}
> ```
>
> Executes `⟨true⟩` if the `⟨string⟩` is an Arabic or Roman numeral, and `⟨false⟩` otherwise. This command is robust. See also `\DeclareNumChars` and `\NumCheckSetup` in § 4.6.4.

The token `A` isn't an arabic nor an roman numeral. As described you can add this token by `\DeclareNumChars`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareNumChars{A}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pages.bib}
@Article{A,
  author =       {Some author},
  title =        {Some title},
  journal =      {Some journal},
  year =         2013,
  pages =        {1A}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{pages.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]