# Bibtex / biber and letters in the pages-Field

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` and MiKTeX to write my thesis. My citations contain articles from a journal which uses a combination of a letter and numbers for the pages. 
The challenge is to cite the article correctly without any errors during compilation of the file because of the `pages`-field.

How can I cite an article, which is printed from page "A-100" to page "A-111" instead of 100-111?

Comment: Do [XIV pages in page counts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16904/35864) and [Biblatex no printing “p.” when page number ends in some letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121021/35864) help? Maybe it's just `\DeclareNumChars*{A}`, you might run into trouble with the `-` in the page number though, normally `biblatex` treats it as a range indicator as in `p. 12-15`.

Comment: An error should never occur even with `pages = {A-100 -- A-111}`, the problem is that the "pagination prefix" might not be added because `biblatex` does not recognise this as a valid page range.

Comment: @moewe: Yeah, it's not an error that's displayed but a warning: "Biber reported the following issues(biblatex) with [citation] :(biblatex) - Range field 'pages' in entry [citation] is malformed, skipping."

Comment: I don't even get a Biber warning with `pages   = {A-427--A-446},` (note the double dash as range separator) while `pages   = {A-427-A-446},` does not fare well with Biber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a combination of two answers (@Sag and @moewe):

First I have to declare "A-" as a number: \DeclareNumChars*{A-} in the preamble; otherwise there is no pagination prefix.

Second I have to use curly brackets to show bibtex that there is only one page range. 
For example:
 Pages = {{A-100}--{A-111}}

Comment: On my system `\DeclareNumChars*{A}` is sufficient (no need for the additional `-`). Also the curly braces are not strictly necessary, if one opts for the double dash. (Biber 2.1/`biblatex` 3 on MikTeX)

Comment: I checked it on my system without the brackets and without a declaration of the numchars. There was either no pagination prefix or a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an extra set of curly brackets: `PAGES = {{A-100}--{A-111}},`  (It worked for me using Biblatex-Chicago.)  Be sure to rebuild you .bbl file.