# Why pp. disappear in the Ref. when I add letters in the pages = "--"?

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

In the Ref. When I have

```
@article{Common,    
.    
.   
Pages = "07104-07109",   
.  
.}
```

I get `pp. 07104-07109`, which is perfect!

But when the pages for example do have a letter such as letter B

```
@article{Common,    
.    
.    
Pages = "07B104-07B109",    
.   
.}
```

I do not get `pp.`! But just get `07B104-07B109`, why `pp.` does not appear?!

I use `biblatex` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Why do your pages have a leading zero? And why would pages have a letter in the middle?

Comment: Did you try to use braces `{07B104-07B109}`?

Comment: Yes I did but still same, no pp.!

Comment: There is, somewhere, a test which checks whether the field contains just numbers or a range or numbers. A few of them are documented which look for integers or ranges. I.e. this is voluntary in some biblatex styles, you can modify it by rewriting the `bibmacro` in which the test is performed.

Comment: Use `\DeclareNumChars*{B}` (the starred version) as described in [Biblatex no printing “p.” when page number ends in some letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121021/35864) and [XIV pages in page counts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16904/35864)

Comment: Is there anything you are missing from the two links above? If not, I will vote to close your question as a duplicate of one of the two in due time.

Comment: Moewe, Now it does work after I used \DeclareNumChars*{B} in the main.tex......Thanks

Comment: So I was right in closing your question, good. Sorry for being a bit impatient there.